# Convert Protobuf to Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I know it is possible to convert protobuf messages to Java classes.  I would like to know is is possible to convert a protobuf message to a Java object without writing translator functions?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It isn't, just pointing you in the right direction to get started. Here let me point it to you more clearly: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#reading-a-message

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes". How does this answer help you? Do you think you wrote a good question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Use protobuf converters. Check: https://github.com/BAData.

**Converting domain object to Protobuf:**

```
ProtoObject protoObject =
    Converter.create().toProtobuf(ProtoObject.class, domainObject);
```

**Converting Protobuf object to domain object:**

```
DomainObject domainObject = Converter.create().toDomain(DomainObject.class, protoObject)
```

Your domain class needs to be annotated with @ProtoClass, specifying the proto class you want the domain class mapped to. Example:

```
@ProtoClass(ProtoObject.class)
Class DomainClass{
  @ProtoField
  private String field1;
  @ProtoField(name = "xyz") // in case proto and domain class field have different names
  private String field2;
}
```

I've been using this and it's quite easy to use and saves a lot of efforts.